# How use a variable case select?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Select Case TextBox1.Text
        Case TextBox1.Text.Contains("string")
            MsgBox("tb 1 contains string")
        Case Else
            Msgbox("Invalid command")
    End Select
End Sub
```

However, I am not sure how to make the case select work in this way, I am trying to make it so that if textbox 1 contains "string" when button 1 is pressed, a msgbox let's the user know. There are no errors thrown by VS, and I can't work out if this is valid code or I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: There's no point, use an If statement instead.

Comment: Wasn't SO about answering questions? He did not ask if to use an If statement or a select case, did he? Maybe we assume that he just TESTS something an therefore presented the most simple example to make his problem clear. Oh, ok: Or he doesn't know about if statements - though he still didnt ask ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make it

```
Select Case True
    Case tb1.Text = "foo" And tb2.Text = "bar" : MsgBox("42")
    Case tb1.Text = "foo" : MsgBox("Missing the bar?")
    Case tb2.Text = "bar" : MsgBox("Without a foo?")
    Case Else : MsgBox("fubar!")
End Select
```

this gives you the freedom to switch on almost everything.

Comment: So why the downvotes, anybody? I understand that `Select Case True` may be considered bad practice by some, but in this case it looks like a nice workaround for the problem. Especially if the number of chained statements increases. Do you think `If...ElseIf...Else` construct would look any better? For single line action statements, it would certainly be more total lines of code. +1

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of cases where `Select Case True` is perfectly acceptable.  Try writing case statements for `Select case _control.GetType` in VB.

Answer (score 2):

Case statements by design are supposed to have defined constant values.  With the small complexity of your logic, it would be better to use an if/else statement instead.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("string") Then
        MsgBox("tb 1 contains string")
    Else
        Msgbox("Invalid command")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't use variable as `case` value. It has to be a constant value.</strike> Use `If`/`Else` statements instead.

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("string") Then
    MsgBox("tb 1 contains string")
Else
    Msgbox("Invalid command")
End If
```

Of using short version of `If`:

```
MsgBox(If(TextBox1.Text.Contains("string"), "tb 1 contains string", "Invalid command"))
```

Comment: Of course you can use a variable as case value. At least in VB.Net.

Comment: @igrimpe: Somehow this never occurred to me. But yes, you are right, this is quite possible in VB.NET - just checked in a test app. +1 for the comment.

Comment: @igrimpe Wow, I though it's not possible in .NET in general (c# does not allow that kind of things). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Taking all existing answers into account, here is how I would write it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim msg As String = GetMessage(TextBox1.Text)
  MessageBox.Show(msg)
End Sub

Private Function GetMessage(text As String) As String
  If text.Contains("string") Then Return "tb 1 contains string"
  Return "Invalid command"
End Function
```